# Can a service “incur” cost someone pays?

Tags: grammar

Is it ok to say:

> The heater will incur a monthly electricity fee.

(Which means that the owner of the heater would have to pay for the heater’s electricity use)

I suspect it is not ok, but I can’t quite describe why. Can someone give me a technical explanation for why this is invalid grammar (or why it is, in fact, ok)?

For a further example, suppose you buy a place with add-on parking, is it ok to say:

> The parking space will incur a $250 monthly fee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence feels wrong because incur is a term that requires an agent who can complete the act - incur the fee. As it is currently stated the transitive verb "incur" is being applied to an object that is incapable of agency.

Adding a word that implies or states the presence of an agent ie. "Usage" to each of these statements would make them logically correct because it is then clear that the user incurs the fee. - ie. "Usage of the heater will incur a monthly fee" or "Users of the heater will incur a monthly fee".

Answer (score 1):

*Incur* basically means to get something unpleasant, such as a bill. These sentences are grammatically correct, but logically wrong. It's not the heater or the parking space that must pay the fee: it's the tenant. So rather than being poor grammar, these are false statements.

See: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/incur

Answer (score 1):

The verb [*incur*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/incur) has a particular usage as defined in Oxford Online Dictionary:

> Become subject to (something unwelcome or unpleasant) ***as a result of
>   one’s own behaviour or actions***: *I will pay any expenses incurred*

You (people) generally incur expenses. A heater or parking space will cost you X amount of money or fee. Contrast the following sentences.

> Under the Local Government Act, a councillor who ***incurs an expense*** in
>   their duty is entitled to be reimbursed.
>
> Some of these benefits ***cost*** significant sums of money to provide.

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

The two verbs are not interchangeable. The sentences look better if rephrased to the followings:

> The heater will ***cost you*** an *extra* monthly electricity fee (bill).
>   The parking space
>   will ***cost you*** a $250 monthly fee.